# Spring boot & Thymeleafで@DateTimeFormatを使ってエラーメッセージを出力する方法

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

springの@DateTimeFormatを使ってactorForm.javaでvalidationしたいのですがmessageという要素が無いが為にエラーページが出力されるだけでエラーメッセージが出力されません。
いろいろと調べたのですがやり方がわかりませんでした。
良ければ教えてもらますか？

これがactorFormです

```
//@Pattern(regexp="(\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2})", message="{actor.validation.birthday}")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd")
    private String birthday;
```

これがControllerです

```
@GetMapping("/actor/create")
  public String create(ActorForm form, Model model) {
    List<Prefecture> pref = prefectureRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("pref", pref);
    return "Actor/create";
  }

  @PostMapping("/actor/save")
  public String save(@Validated @ModelAttribute ActorForm form, BindingResult result, Model model, Locale locale) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
      String message = msg.getMessage("actor.validation.error", null, locale);
      model.addAttribute("errorMessage", message);
      return create(form, model);
    }
    Actor actor = convert(form);
    actor = actorRepository.saveAndFlush(actor);
    return "redirect:/actor/" + actor.getId().toString();
  }

/**
   * convert form to model.
   */
  private Actor convert(ActorForm form) {
    Actor actor = new Actor();
    actor.setName(form.getName());
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(form.getHeight())) {
      actor.setHeight(Integer.valueOf(form.getHeight()));
    }
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(form.getBlood())) {
      actor.setBlood(form.getBlood());
    }
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(form.getBirthday())) {
      DateTimeFormatter withoutZone = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
      LocalDateTime parsed = LocalDateTime.parse(form.getBirthday() + " 00:00:00", withoutZone);
      Instant instant = parsed.toInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(9));
      actor.setBirthday(Date.from(instant));
    }
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(form.getBirthplaceId())) {
      actor.setBirthplaceId(Integer.valueOf(form.getBirthplaceId()));
    }
    actor.setUpdateAt(new Date());
    return actor;
  }
```

propertiesファイル

```
# @DateTimeFormat
typeMismatch=  is invalid.
typeMismatch.int=  must be an integer.
typeMismatch.double=  must be a double.
typeMismatch.float=  must be a float.
typeMismatch.long=  must be a long.
typeMismatch.short=  must be a short.
typeMismatch.actorForm.java.lang.Integer=  must be an integer.
typeMismatch.actorForm.java.lang.Double=  must be a double.
typeMismatch.actorForm.java.lang.Float=  must be a float.
typeMismatch.actorForm.java.lang.Long=  must be a long.
typeMismatch.actorForm.java.lang.Short=  must be a short.
typeMismatch.actorForm.java.util.Date=  is not a date.
typeMismatch.actorForm.birthday=aaaaaaaaaa
typeMismatch.birthday=aaaaaaaa
```

htmlファイル

```
<form role="form" action="/actor/save" th:action="@{/actor/save}" th:object="${actorForm}"
          method="post">

<!-- birthday -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="id_birthday" class="col-sm-2 control-label" th:utext="#{actor.birthday}">birthday</label>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <input id="id_birthday" class="form-control" type="text" name="birthday" th:field="*{birthday}" th:placeholder="#{actor.create.birthday}"/>
              <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('birthday')}" th:errors="*{birthday}" class="help-block">error!</span>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`@DateTimeFormat`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) は `String`でなく日付時刻型に付与するのが正しいかと思います。

**`ActorForm.java`**:

```
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "uuuu/MM/dd")
    private LocalDate birthday;
```

また、コントローラで使用しているメッセージプロパティ `actor.validation.error` も必要です。

**`messages.properties`**:

```
actor.validation.error=error occurred
```

([差分](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/commit/aef0b4befdd1de5434499247e2915fa71642da3e))

Comment: 動きましたありがとうございます。エラーメッセージはtypeMismatch.actorForm.birthdayで動きました。